# Get rid of overlapping bounding boxes across different classes in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection, bounding-box, object-detection-api

I am using the Tensorflow Object Detection API to train my own vehicle detector. When I tested my model using the [Object detection tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb), I found that there are instances when a truck is detected as both a car and a truck with two overlapping bounding boxes around it. I only want to leave the one with the highest detection score.

I know that the Object Detection API does get rid of overlapping bounding boxes, but it does not do so for bounding boxes across different classes. Is there a way to get rid of the overlapping boxes? Is there any place in the Object Detection API code that I can change to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use non_max_suppression over all classes:

```
  corners = tf.constant(boxes, tf.float32)
  boxesList = box_list.BoxList(corners)
  boxesList.add_field('scores', tf.constant(scores))
  iou_thresh = 0.1
  max_output_size = 100
  sess = tf.Session()
  nms = box_list_ops.non_max_suppression(
      boxesList, iou_thresh, max_output_size)
  boxes = sess.run(nms.get())
```

Comment: Ok. I will try to do that. Thank you!

Comment: where did you get the value for "box_list"?

Comment: how do you manage the scenario where you have multiple instances of the same class within the same image?

Answer (score 1):

there are two ways to get rid of the overlapping bounding boxes.

1st, set the "min_score_thresh" parameter bigger at "visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array" function in file [visualization_utils.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py);

2nd, set the non-max-suppression threshold in config file